# cron job not running /bin/bash: user: command not found

Tags: cron, crontab

I'm trying to run a cron job that executes a script as a user using crontab -e on ubuntu server 16.04 LTS.  The script is and located in /data/autoremove.sh:

> ## !/usr/bin/env bash
>
> if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 1.1.1.1 >/dev/null; then    scp /data/Data*
>   user@1.1.1.1:/data && rm data* else
>       echo "does not work" fi

and the cron job is being configured with the user "user":

`*/1 * * * * /data/autoremove.sh>/dev/null 2> ~/cron.err`.

I have tried adding both a `SHELL=/bin/bash` and a `PATH=` to both the crontab and the script, and confirmed that cron is running, and attempted to run it without declaring a user. The script works when running it either as root or the owner

The error I am getting is `/bin/bash: user: command not found'`  I've gone through multiple articles on the different stacks sites and not had any luck getting this to work.

Comment: Why do you think that's how you specify the user to run it as?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams because that is what the manual says https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto ...don't think I understand what you are getting at.

Comment: When you using user's cron, you shouldn't specify `user`, it is applied only to system cron. Other things - use everywhere full paths

Comment: Error in first line: replace it to `#!/bin/bash` instead of `!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: `~/autoremove.sh` is in your home directory, while `/data/autoremove.sh` is in the directory `/data`

Comment: "Here's an example line from a fictitious **/etc/crontab**:" But you aren't editing `/etc/crontab`, you're using `crontab -e`.

Comment: if I move it to /etc/crontab and declare the user or if i remove the user and enter it in crontab -e the results are the same it can't find the file

Comment: Did you tried what I advised you - "use everywhere full paths"?

Comment: Yes tried it @Alex

Comment: Even for `ping`, `scp`, `rm` ???